# How can I edit videos taken with the camera?

Tags: video

Is there a way to make basic edits, like cropping, to videos captured with the phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built into the phone, and I don't see any app that provide it either. There are apps that work with photos, but I don't see one for video.

So it looks like you need to sync the device with your computer and edit there. Live Movie Maker is a free offering from Microsoft that will let you do this.